# key capture using global hotkey in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook, global-hotkey

I have a application that runs in the background like i may keep my app in the system tray.If it remains on system tray my app will do it's job. Whenever a user press F10 or F9 some works will be done. i tried this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int a = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);


    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Int32 vKey);

    const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int) Keys.F9);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int)Keys.F10);

        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID && (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F9) == -32767))
        {
            if ((a % 2) != 0)
            {
                a++;
                MessageBox.Show(a.ToString()+"not equal F9");
                label1.Text = "not equal F9";
            }

            if ((a % 2) == 0)
            {
                a++;
                MessageBox.Show(a.ToString()+"equal F9");
                label1.Text = " equal F9";
            }

        }

        else if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID && (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F10) == -32767))
        {
            if ((a % 2) != 0)
            {
                a++;
                MessageBox.Show(a.ToString() + "not equal F10");
                label1.Text = "not equal F10";
            }

            if ((a % 2) == 0)
            {
                a++;
                MessageBox.Show(a.ToString() + "equal F10");
                label1.Text = " equal F10";
            }

        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}
```

As i use set "this.ShowInTaskbar = false" this line it doesn't work.But if i don't set this it works fine.For my app i have to use this line.How can i solve this????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to subscribe to certain messages that the operating system sends by means of a native function call like `RegisterHotKey()`. When you call this function You tell the operating system which window to send the messages to by specifying the `Handle` of the window, this can be considered an address. When you set `ShowInTaskbar = false` the handle changes so the operating system will not know where to reach you.

See the first arugment:

```
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int) Keys.F9);
```

To resolve your issue you can create a class that derives from [`NativeWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) which "*Provides a low-level encapsulation of a window handle and a window procedure.*" and from within that class (or at least using that class's handle depending on your implementation), register the hotkeys using a handle that will never change.

```
public sealed class HotkeyManager : NativeWindow, IDisposable
{
    public HotkeyManager()
    {
        CreateHandle(new CreateParams());
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == Constants.WM_HOTKEY)
        {
             //handle hotkey message
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DestroyHandle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need to re-register the hotkey whenever you change the "ShowInTaskbar" state.

Someone else had a similar problem; see [this thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/registerhotkey-and-showintaskbar-t1236248.html).